# Titanium : How to abort a service call when the BACK button is presses in ANDROID?

Tags: android, service, titanium-mobile, back-button, thread-abort

In **Titanium**, I have implemented a screen which I have a button which calls a service call and once the response is received it navigates to the next screen. I have added an activity indicator to the 1st screen until a response is received.

While this activity indicator is working if the user presses the **BACK** button in **ANDROID**, the application exits and shows the message **“The application has stopped unexpectedly”**.

Is there any way to abort a service call if the user pressed the **BACK** button in **ANDROID** and land him on the same screen or exit the application without any errors?

Answer (score 0):

I would check if the service call you are making has any hooks that have eventListeners tied onto it before the action is processed. It's doubtful that there will be one, but it's worth a look.

I would assume that once the service call is sent it is then asynchronously updated and you won't have a chance.

But if you are calling an API response for example you can set a timeout value and an error catch that is fired in such case.

e.g.

```
var url = "serviceURL";
var xhr = Ti.Network.createHTTPClient({
    onload: function(e) {
        // this.responseText holds the raw text return of the message (used for JSON)
        // this.responseXML holds any returned XML (used for SOAP web services)
        // this.responseData holds any returned binary data

        Ti.API.debug(this.responseText);
        alert('success');
    },
    onerror: function(e) {
        Ti.API.debug(e.error);
        alert('error');
    },
    timeout:5000
});
```

In the error function you can then close the loading wheel object.

eg.

```
loadingWheel.close();
```

and then direct the user to a different window using the original window context.

Another option to implement this is to wait for a response from the service and write a basic timeout function that is aborted before the service returns a result back. You can error catch this and not load the new window before it returns in a reasonable amount of time, whilst still presenting a loading wheel to the user.